# Undeclared functions returning pointers in x86-64 lead to invalid pointer expansion

Tags: c, pointers, size, x86-64, expansion

I just spend half a day figuring a subtle crash in x86-64 code, so this a heads-up to others - I have not seen this treated elsewhere.

If you use a libc function without having a proper declaration, gcc *will assume that it returns int*. E.g. **setlocale()** is assumed to be **int setlocale()**, with a 32-bit int value returned in EAX.

Trying to convert this return to a pointer, either through implicit or explicit cast, will force a conversion from 32-bit to 64-bit through sign expansion, even if the called function returned a valid 64-bin pointer value in RAX ! E.g.

```
    char *p = setlocale(0, 0);      // bear with me for a second
```

gets compiled to

```
    1c: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    21: e8 00 00 00 00          callq  26 <hard_locale+0x26>
    26: 48 98                   cltq   ;   <--- eax is expanded in rax
```

GCC even tries to tell you this:

```
    warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

If you add an explicit cast, the warning changes to, which shows the problem:

```
    warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

If you're lucky, nothing happens, but if it happens to return a large value for a pointer up in the memory, it will be messed up, as follows:

```
    function returns in RAX: 0x07ffff7b9705e
    cltq considers EAX with negative sign: 0xf7b9705e
    now RAX is: 0xfffffffff7b9705e
```

and your pointer is invalid.

Fixes and solutions:

- always use proper function declarations
- **-Wall -Werror** should be default on in x86-64 compilers.

Comment: Well, yes, if you don't declare a function that you use, you're gonna have a bad time. I think that's well known, as is the need to always enable as many compiler warnings as you can. I don't think spelling out a lot of assembly for what is essentially a basic type error is terribly enlightening...

Comment: This is expected behaviour for C. The solution is to fix any warnings raised by the compiler, which would include "call to undeclared function."

Comment: Much of the blame for this issue should attach to the compiler writers who decided to keep `int` at 32 bits; 64-bit data models where `int` is 64 bits (the natural data size for the platform) will handle the situation just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Undeclared functions are **not valid C**. Just add `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` and the problem will go away. You don't need to make other warnings (which are mostly sylistic considerations) into errors.

Here is a list of warning-as-error options for GCC to reject invalid C without any false positives. It misses some things (which GCC has no support for catching) but it's mostly complete:

- `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`
- `-Werror=implicit-int`
- `-Werror=pointer-sign`
- `-Werror-pointer-arith`
- `-Werror=return-type`
- `-std=c99` (or `-std=c11`, etc., as desired)
- `-pedantic-errors` (optional; rejects some code that's *valid* but not fully portable)

Note that I had initially also added `-Werror=sequence-point` and `-Werror=array-bounds` to the list, but they have false positives because they do not mark constraint violations, only runtime UB. As such, a program that contains such warnings can still be a correct program as long as the code that would invoke UB is unreachable (as a good example, think of branches like `if (sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)) { ... } else { ... }` where the not-taken branch invokes UB based on the results of the `sizeof` operator).

Answer (score 1):

It's an old joke. I described a similar situation here: [A nice 64-bit error in C](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0033/).

To avoid these and other errors, it is useful read article ["A Collection of Examples of 64-bit Errors in Real Programs](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0065/)" and use [Viva64 rules](http://www.viva64.com/en/viva64-tool/).